# WSDL elements order

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

In an application, I have web services that are based on WSDL files provided by a third-party company. All I did until now, was generating the associated Java code by using an ant script with axis wsdl2java.

I say until now because the company which provide the web services has modified its architecture and the soap messages must know respect the order of the input elements which is apparently not the case.

Example : in my WSDL I have something like this

```
<xs:element name="personinfo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But when I look at the soap message that is sent to the web service, the order of the elements are not the same as in the WSDL file.

Do you guys have any idea on what do I have to do in order to make the elements order respected in the message that I send ?

EDIT : I use Axis 1.4

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: You make no mention of which web services framework that you are using. Axis? Axis2? CXF? Each will consume and generate classes differently. It might also be useful to provide a copy of the WSDL and the SOAP message that you're having problems consuming.

Comment: I'm using Axis 1.4, sorry.

Comment: Reading this again... SO after the remote service provider upgraded his services, you are stating that the new SOAP message format is no longer valid when compared to the published WSDL? The WSDL is supposed to capture the contract between service consumer and service provider. Are you sure the WSDL has not been changed as well?

Comment: In fact, the remote service provider has upgraded the security checks. In particular, they now check the order of the elements in the input messages (which they didn't do before) and they tell me that the order in the messages I send to them is not correct. I checked myself and indeed, one element is not at the good place. It'as only a question of order because it worked fine until now. They sent me the latest version of the WSDL and it is correct compared to the one I use.

Comment: So you're implying that Axis 1.4 is generating Java classes that produce an invalid SOAP message? If that is the case I suggest either submitting a bug report or switching to an alternative web services framework like Axis2 or CXF (Axis 1.4 was released in 2006).

Comment: If it was up to me, I wouldn't use Axis 1.4. Bur unfortunately, I have no choice. But I found a workaround and, despite I'm not sure why it solves my issue, it seems to be working. Thanks for your help Mark.